# How to consolidate duplicate values with 2 different variables

Tags: excel, vba

The table below is my data. I would like to consolidate the data such that if there is duplicates of `Sno.` and batch the `qty` will add up tgt.

So you can see that only row 5 and 6, both have the same `Sno.` and `batch`, so the `qty` will add up tgt (as seen in the 2nd table), the rest remains the same.

| Sno. | batch | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3935 | 0121 | 100 |
| 3935 | 0151 | 546 |
| 0143 | 2245 | 2164 |
| 0183 | 2245 | 459 |
| 3400 | 798B | 798 |
| 3400 | 798B | 1000 |
| 5495 | 015E | 785 |

So, it should come out like this.

Consolidated:

| Sno. | batch | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3935 | 0121 | 100 |
| 3935 | 0151 | 546 |
| 0143 | 2245 | 2164 |
| 0183 | 2245 | 459 |
| 3400 | 798B | 1798 |
| 5495 | 015E | 785 |

Comment: 1. Did you check out Pivot Tables? 2. What have you tried to solve your issue? Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: hi. i did manage to use consolidate under data tools, however it is only able to have 1 variable. But for my case i would like to find out if there is another way if it is possible to have 2 variables. (like Sno. and batch).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `=UNIQUE(A1:B8, 0, 0)` formula on the Sno and Batch columns to get the unique list
2. Make the qty column with a sumifs `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,E2,$B$2:$B$8,F2)` (This has the unique formula in E1)
3. Combine a concatenation with a textjoin to get the output `="|"&TEXTJOIN("|",0,E2:G2)&"|"` (This has the qty column in G)

Here's a pic of the output:

[image]

Here's a pic of the formulae:
[image]

Comment: Worth to mention that `=UNIQUE` only works with Microsoft 365 but not with older versions of Excel.

Comment: @MTwem thanks alot. I managed to consolidate the data i need. thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Would you mind doing the acceptance thing for me? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365).

It has a `GroupBy` function and select  `SUM` for the operation

- Select some cell in the table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- Select the Sno and Batch Columns, then `GroupBy` and select your operation:

[image]

- Close and Load

**Generated M Code**

```
let

    //Note you will need to change table name to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sno.", Int64.Type}, {"batch", type any}, {"qty", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Sno.", "batch"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([qty]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]